# webpack inlines the CSS as a string inside the JS bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been reading about webpack and I finally got what webpack does basically. I need many advanced features of webpack too. So I am trying to learn webpacks features as much as I can.

So, I was reading another great source for webpack. But as I ll provide the github wiki link of this page, It says something I don t get.

> When you require CSS (or less, etc), webpack inlines the CSS as a string inside the JS bundle and require() will insert a  tag into the page. When you require images, webpack inlines a URL to the image into the bundle and returns it from require().

Link for the source is 
[webpack-howto | Stylesheets and images](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#5-stylesheets-and-images)

I hope someone helps me clear things out with this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `myStyle.css` with the content:

```
.something { color: red; }
```

When you (in your `.js` file) do a:

```
require('./myStyle.css');
```

then Webpack will read that style document and output it in a `<style>` tag in your HTML document, e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        .something { color: red; }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Same thing with images. If you in your js do:

```
const imageUrl = require('/path/to/your/image');
```

Then Webpack will make sure that that image is copied into your build/dist folder and that it's given a unique name (e.g. 15be437...). And your imageUrl variable will be set to that unique name.

All of this is configurable. You can [make Webpack output a regular .css file](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) instead of inlining it. You can make images into Base64 images etc.